# track.stop is not turning the camera off anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediadevices

I have a webpage where I want user to take a picture with his laptop/phone camera.
Once he clicks on a button a modal is shown and the following js will start the camera stream to take the picture:

```
    function startStreaming() {
        if (null != cameraStream) {
            var track = cameraStream.getTracks()[0];
            track.stop();
            stream.load();
            cameraStream = null;
        }
        //const audioSource = audioInputSelect.value;
        const videoSource = videoSelect.value;
        const constraints = {
            //audio: {deviceId: audioSource ? {exact: audioSource} : undefined},
            video: {
                deviceId: videoSource ? {
                    exact: videoSource
                } : undefined
            }
        };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(gotStream).then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
        var mediaSupport = 'mediaDevices' in navigator;
        if (mediaSupport && null == cameraStream) {
            const videoSource = videoSelect.value;
            const constraints = {
                video: {
                    deviceId: videoSource ? {
                        exact: videoSource
                    } : undefined
                }
            };
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                .then(function (mediaStream) {
                    cameraStream = mediaStream;
                    stream.srcObject = mediaStream;
                    stream.play();
                })
                .catch(handleError);
        } else {
            alert('Your browser does not support media devices.');
            return;
        }
    }
```

This is triggered by

```
            $('#photoStudio').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
                startStreaming();
            });
```

Then when I close the modal I want to stop the streaming but the led indicator next to my camera is still on)

```
            $('#photoStudio').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
                stopStreaming();
            });
```

where `stopStreaming()` is:

```
    function stopStreaming() {
        if (null != cameraStream) {
            var track = cameraStream.getTracks()[0];
            track.stop();
            stream.load();
            cameraStream = null;
        }
    }
```

I don't get any kind of error and I cannot find a way to debug why the camera is still running. Am I missing anything in the stopStreaming function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If any track has not been stopped then your camera will still be active. In your `stopStreaming` function you only stop the first track in the returned array.

If you instead iterate through the tracks you may catch ones you aren't currently:

```
    function stopStreaming() {
        if (null != cameraStream) {
            var tracks = cameraStream.getTracks();
           // stop all the tracks, not just the first
            tracks.forEach((track) => {
                track.stop();
           });
            stream.load();
            cameraStream = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.camera_stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    console.log(track);
    track.stop();
    **track.enabled = false**        
});
video.load()
this.camera_stream = null
```